# How do I keep the auth state and prevent re logging in each time i refresh the page or navigate to another page using firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can't seem to figure out how to maintain the login state.

I login, the app shows the condition if logged in, but then if I refresh the page, it asks me to login again.

I am using onAuthStateChanged, I just dont know what else to do.

This shows up when user not logged in
[image]

after I click login, this shows up
[image]

but when i click refresh, it shows you must login again.

here is my firebase config (the relevant bits)

```js
function useAuth() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) =>
      setCurrentUser(user)
    );
    return unsubsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return currentUser;
}
export { app, storage, auth, database, useAuth };
```

I decide to create a function useAuth() inside firebase.config so i dont have to recreate it everywhere i need it.

Here is the login code

```js
const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const currentUser = useAuth();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);      

  function login(email, password) {
    return auth
      .setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence)
      .then(() => {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(error);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  }
```

And here is the page I want to show if the user is logged in. It shows to correct component if logged in , but when i refresh the page it doesnt remember the logged in user.

here is the code for the page

```js
const Properties = () => {
  const currentUser = useAuth();

  onAuthStateChanged(auth,(user))

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Add Property</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="web dev" />
      </Head>
      <h1>Add Property</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the add Property new</p>
      {console.log("user logged in? " + currentUser?.email)}

      {currentUser ? (
        <AddProperty />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p style={{ color: "red" }}>You must be loggedin to add a property</p>{" "}
          <Login />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Properties;
```

Comment: On most browsers Firebase Authentication automatically persists the authentication state, so I'd first test by removing `auth.setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence)`.

Comment: thats how I had it first, but i get the same effect